# is there any way to fetch n number of record start form x row?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to fetch 50 records from table which contains millions of record **without using limit**

I did following

```
private void createMYSQLConnection() throws SQLException {
        CachedRowSet crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb",
                    "root", "root");

            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            crs.setPageSize(100);
            crs.setUsername("root");
            crs.setPassword("Glass4#21");
            crs.setCommand("SELECT * FROM trn_22_gouk_final_attendance");
            crs.absolute(10);
            crs.setFetchSize(10);
            crs.execute(conn);
            while (crs.next()) {
                System.out.println(crs.getObject(1));
            }

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            crs.close();
        }
    }
```

but it not works...
any suggestion

Thanks in advance

Comment: I feel you need add row number clause for that rather than fetch count

Comment: This might be helpful: http://java.avdiel.com/Tutorials/JDBCPaging.html

Comment: i dont want to write code to be database specific
according to : java.avdiel.com/Tutorials/JDBCPaging.html 
for mysql i have to use `limit` for oracle i have to use `rowNum`
but i want code that is independent to database

Answer (score 1):

JDBC's 'fetch size' was not intended for limiting the result-set, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440543/what-is-the-difference-between-setting-statement-fetch-size-in-jdbc-or-firing-a).

JDBC does not have an API for pagination, see the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771439/jdbc-pagination).

Since the keywords for pagination are different for each database type, something needs to translate the specified pagination for the database used. Hibernate can do that, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840108/3080094).