# What is the difference between Statement.setMaxRows vs Statement.setFetchsize in Hive

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am running queries against Hive. The same queries are supposed to work with other JDBC drivers, meaning, other relational databases.

I can't use the method Statement.setFetchSize, because it is not supported in the Hive JDBC 0.13.0.

I am trying to work this around, therefore, I came to another similar method: **Statement.setMaxRows**

In which cases should I use Statement.setMaxRows vs Statement.setFetchsize?

Is it possible to use them interchangeably?

Thanks.

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440543/what-is-the-difference-between-setting-statement-fetch-size-in-jdbc-or-firing-a

Comment: Are you sure that "setFetchsize" is not supported in Hive V0.13.0?? Then why don't you use the V0.13.1 driver *(or 0.14 etc.)* against your V0.13.0 service?

Comment: You may also want to know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707682/jdbc-limit-vs-setmaxrowsresultset

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't use them interchangeably. They do different things. The setMaxRows = number of rows that can be returned overall. setFetchSize = number that will be returned in each database roundtrip i.e.

> [setFetchSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int)) Gives the JDBC driver a hint as to the
>   number of rows that should be fetched from the database when more rows
>   are needed for ResultSet objects genrated by this Statement.
>
> [setMaxRows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setMaxRows(int)) Sets the limit for the maximum number of rows
>   that any ResultSet object generated by this Statement object can
>   contain to the given number.

In fact since setFetchSize is a hint the driver is free to ignore this and do what it sees fit. So don't worry about Hive JDBC not supporting this.

Note that all that setMaxRows is doing is

> reducing the size of the ResultSet object. It won't affect the speed
>   of the query. setMaxRows doesn't change the actual SQL - using
>   top/limit/rownum e.g. - so it doesn't change the work the DB does. The
>   query will return more results than your limit if there are more
>   results to return, then truncate them to fit your ResultSet.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15559710/4807777) does a good job of explaining how setFetchSize is important:

> very important to performance and memory-management within the JVM as
>   it controls the number of network calls from the JVM to the database
>   and correspondingly the amount of RAM used for ResultSet processing.

---

**Btw**, setFetchSize can be set on java.sql.Statement as well as java.sql.ResultSet. The default value is set by the Statement object that created the result set. The fetch size may be changed at any time. And Hive JDBC has it's own [HiveQueryResultSet with a setFetchSize method](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/jdbc/HiveQueryResultSet.html#setFetchSize(int)).