# SQL LIMIT vs. JDBC Statement setMaxRows. Which one is better?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, limit

I want to select the Top 10 records for a given query. So, I can use one of the following options:

- Using the JDBC [`Statement.setMaxRows()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setMaxRows(int)) method
- Using LIMIT and OFFSET in the SQL query

What are the advantages and disadvantages of these two options?

Answer (score 26):

### SQL-level LIMIT

To restrict the SQL query result set size, you can use the SQL:008 syntax:

```
SELECT title
FROM post
ORDER BY created_on DESC
OFFSET 50 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

which works on Oracle 12, SQL Server 2012, or PostgreSQL 8.4 or newer versions.

For MySQL, you can use the LIMIT and OFFSET clauses:

```
SELECT title
FROM post
ORDER BY created_on DESC
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 50
```

The advantage of using the SQL-level pagination is that the database execution plan can use this information.

So, if we have an index on the `created_on` column:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_post_created_on ON post (created_on DESC)
```

And we execute the following query that uses the `LIMIT` clause:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT title
FROM post
ORDER BY created_on DESC
LIMIT 50
```

We can see that the database engine uses the index since the optimizer knows that only 50 records are to be fetched:

```
Execution plan:
Limit  (cost=0.28..25.35 rows=50 width=564)
       (actual time=0.038..0.051 rows=50 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using idx_post_created_on on post p  
      (cost=0.28..260.04 rows=518 width=564) 
      (actual time=0.037..0.049 rows=50 loops=1)
Planning time: 1.511 ms
Execution time: 0.148 ms
```

### JDBC Statement maxRows

According to the [`setMaxRows` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setMaxRows(int)):

> If the limit is exceeded, the excess rows are silently dropped.

That's not very reassuring!

So, if we execute the following query on PostgreSQL:

```
try (PreparedStatement statement = connection
    .prepareStatement("""
        SELECT title
        FROM post
        ORDER BY created_on DESC
    """)
) {
    statement.setMaxRows(50);
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    int count = 0;
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        String title = resultSet.getString(1);
        count++;
    }
}
```

We get the following execution plan in the PostgreSQL log:

```
Execution plan:
  Sort  (cost=65.53..66.83 rows=518 width=564) 
        (actual time=4.339..5.473 rows=5000 loops=1)
  Sort Key: created_on DESC
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 896kB
  ->  Seq Scan on post p  (cost=0.00..42.18 rows=518 width=564) 
                          (actual time=0.041..1.833 rows=5000 loops=1)
Planning time: 1.840 ms
Execution time: 6.611 ms
```

Because the database optimizer has no idea that we need to fetch only 50 records, it assumes that all 5000 rows need to be scanned. If a query needs to fetch a large number of records, the cost of a full-table scan is actually lower than if an index is used, hence the execution plan will not use the index at all.

> I ran this test on Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and MySQL, and it looks like the Oracle and PostgreSQL optimizers don't use the `maxRows` setting when generating the execution plan.
>
> However, on SQL Server and MySQL, the `maxRows` JDBC setting is taken into consideration, and the execution plan is equivalent to an SQL query that uses `TOP` or `LIMIT`. You can run the tests for yourself, as they are available in my [High-Performance Java Persistence GitHub repository](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/commit/99f89cb13107516402bcd188fa484170d41bc69e).

### Conclusion

Although it looks like the `setMaxRows` is a portable solution to limit the size of the `ResultSet`, the SQL-level pagination is much more efficient if the database server optimizer doesn't use the JDBC `maxRows` property.

Answer (score 4):

For most cases, you want to use the `LIMIT` clause, but at the end of the day both will achieve what you want. This answer is targeted at JDBC and PostgreSQL, but is applicable to other languages and databases that use a similar model.

The JDBC documentation for [`Statement.setMaxRows`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setMaxRows-int-) says

> If the limit is exceeded, the excess rows are silently dropped.

i.e. The database server may return more rows but the client will just ignore them. The PostgreSQL JDBC driver limits on both the client and server side. For the client side, have a look at the usage of [`maxRows` in the `AbstractJdbc2ResultSet`](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java#L728). For the server side, have a look of [`maxRows` in `QueryExecutorImpl`](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/org/postgresql/core/v3/QueryExecutorImpl.java#L171).

Server side, the [PostgreSQL `LIMIT` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html) says:

> The query optimizer takes LIMIT into account when generating a query
>   plan

So as long as the query is sensible, it will load only the data it needs to fulfill the query.

Comment: I think you are wrong about: 'appears to limit only on the client side'. You can look at `org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl#sendOneQuery` method.

Comment: I do believe you're right @sibnick. I'll update the answer. Without looking at the server source code, I guess it's _possible_ that the server could ignore the information, but that seems unlikely (and a bad move).

Comment: Under some circumstances it has to compute the whole result set before it can return only some of it, but it tries to choose a plan to avoid doing that. In those cases it's the same if you use a LIMIT.

Answer (score 3):

**setFetchSize** Gives the JDBC driver a hint as to the number of rows that should be fetched from the database when more rows are needed for ResultSet objects generated by this Statement.

**setMaxRows** Sets the limit for the maximum number of rows that any ResultSet object generated by this Statement object can contain to the given number.

I guess using above 2 JDBC API you can try by using setFetchSize you can try if it works for 100K records. Else you can fetch in batch and form ArrayList and return it to your Jasper report.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if i am right, but i remember in the past i was involved in big project to change all queries that were expected to return one row into 'TOP 1' or numrows=1. Reason was that the DB would stop searching for 'next possible matches' when this 'hint' was used. And in high volume environments this really made a difference. The remark that you can 'ignore' superfluous records in the client or in the resultset is not enough. You should avoid unnecessary reads as early as possible. But i have no idea whether the JDBC methods add those db specific hints  to the query y/n. I may need to test however to see and use it ...  i am not db specialist and can imagine i am not right, but "Speedwise it seems like no difference" can be a wrong assumption ... E.g. if you are asked to search in box for red balls and you only need one, it does not add value to keep searching for all where for you one is enough ... Then it matters to specify 'TOP 1' ...